# Detect MacBook lid open/close with Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to detect MacBook lid open/close events in Swift?
I searched a lot but didn't find a way in swift.

Comment: Is detecting sleep/wake "good enough"?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I need to detect closing the lid

Comment: What if it is connected to an external display and running with the lid closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by executing a terminal command in my app. Here is the code:

```
func lidClosed() -> Bool {
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    process.arguments = ["-c", "ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState -d 4 | grep AppleClamshellState  | head -1"]
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.launch()
    if(String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)?.contains("Yes") ?? false){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```